# fast jquery image slide show

Tags: jquery, ajax, slideshow

as we know that in jquery / Ajax we have lot of slide show projects, but i am looking for fast slide show of images specially for slow internet connections,

most of the scripts load all the image on page load which make it slow.

one idea may be it load one or two images at a time then load next two images once page is loaded and continue until load all.

any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jQuery Cycle](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) allows you to dynamically add slides to a slideshow.

There is a [demo](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/add3.html) which features preloading additional images for an existing slideshow, then dynamically adding them through a callback. The slideshow is initially displayed with only two images.

This would seem to fit your requirements?

Answer (score 2):

[Camera plugin](http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/) has lots of features and supports lazy loading of images.

Comment: I was searching for this kind of plugin. and it works for me great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using Lazy Load plugin for JQuery.
[Lazy Load plugin homepage](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)